# MASM Calculating Composites

Tags: assembly, masm

I am trying to run code that asks the user for an input between 1 and 400 and gives that number of composites. Ex. Input of 31 would yield
4 6 8 9 10 12 14 15 16 18
20 21 22 24 25 26 27 28 30 32
33 34 35 36 38 39 40 42 44 45 46

The following code crashes when I attempt to run it:

```
        userInt1    DWORD   ?           ;integer to be entered by user
    userInt2    DWORD   ?           ;integer to be entered by user
    intro_1     BYTE    "Composite Numbers  by. Eric Walters" , 0
    prompt_1    BYTE    "Enter the number of composite numbers you would like to see. ", 0
    prompt_2    BYTE    "I'll accept orders for up to 400 composites. ", 0
    prompt_3    BYTE    "Enter the number of composites to display [1 .. 400]: ", 0
    prompt_4    BYTE    "Test", 0
    prompt_6    BYTE    "Results certified by Eric Walters.",0
    prompt_7    BYTE    "Goodbye, ", 0
    outOfRange  BYTE    "Out of range. Try again.",0
    goodBye     BYTE    "Impressed? Bye! ", 0
    upperLevel  DWORD   400         ;the largest integer allowed
    lowerLevel  DWORD   1           ;the smallest integer allowed
    newArray    DWORD   500 DUP(?)


.code
main PROC

push    OFFSET newArray
push    ebp
mov     ebp,esp
mov     esi,[ebp + 8]


; Introduction  

    mov     edx, OFFSET intro_1
    call    WriteString
    call    CrLf
    call    CrLf
    mov     edx, OFFSET prompt_1
    call    WriteString
    call    CrLf
    mov     edx, OFFSET prompt_2
    call    WriteString
    call    CrLf
    call    CrLf

; getUserData
    userPrompt:
        mov     edx, OFFSET prompt_3
        call    WriteString
        call    ReadInt
        mov     userInt1, eax
        mov     eax, userInt1

    ;validate   
        cmp     eax, upperLevel
        ja      option1
        cmp     eax, lowerLevel
        jb      option1
        jmp     option2

    option1 :
        mov     edx, OFFSET outOfRange
        call    WriteString
        call    crlf
        jmp     userPrompt

    mov     ecx, 4
    option2 :
        cmp     ecx, userInt1
        jnle    done
        mov     ebx, 2  

    showComposites :
        mov     edx, ecx
        sub     edx, 1
        cmp     ebx, edx
        jge     L1
        mov     eax, ecx
        div     ebx
        cmp     edx, 0
        je      composite

    resume :
        inc     ebx
        jmp     showComposites

    L1:
        inc     ecx
        jmp     option2

    done :
        pop     ebp
        ret     4

    composite:
        mov     [esi], ecx
        add     esi, TYPE DWORD
        jmp     L1

; farewell
    mov     edx, OFFSET prompt_6
    call    WriteString
    call    crlf
    mov     edx, OFFSET prompt_7
    call    WriteString
    call    crlf


    exit        ; exit to operating system
main ENDP

END main
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The fact that you don't appear to clear `edx` prior to the `div` looks suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you did NOT fail to assemble an exe so your EXTRN/PUBLIC declarations are in order.

```
jmp     userPrompt

mov     ecx, 4           ;Useless code?

option2 :
cmp     ecx, userInt1    ;Not understanding when ECX is initialized and
jnle    done             ;why, was it suppose to be the above code
mov     ebx, 2           ;that is misplaced?
```

This part threw me off and now I don't understand your algorithm for sequential composite numbers.

Here's an idea: Why not just set up an array of 1-400 composite numbers and have the user input between 1-400 be a loop counter to a loop that would display each array element? (Not as efficient on time and memory as a good algorithm though.)

Comment: This looks more like a comment asking the OP for clarification than an answer.

Comment: Couldn't comment on OP question without 50 rep. Best answer I could give.

Comment: I guess the problem I'm having is a fundamental misunderstanding of how to implement finding composite numbers in assembly code. Say I wanted to set up and array of 1-400 composite numbers, how would do I implement that array?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't run your code, I want to be honest:I hate NASM and all it's high level directives and macros.

My best guess is this

```
    push    OFFSET newArray
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp,esp
    mov     esi,[ebp + 8]

    ;Whole lotta stuff

done:
    pop     ebp
    ret     4
```

Maybe you were copy-pasting code, I don't know, but this set the return address of the *main* proc to the address of `newArray` and will crash on return.
I see how you have tried to pass the array as an argument but there is not function you called.

The rest of the code, beside the point highlighted by Nhat M Le in its answer, should work or require minor adjustment (note that I haven't run it).

---

## May I give you some advice?

**1. Give a description of the algorithm and the problem**

When you post code, specially assembly code, give a general description of the algorithm you are implementing.

Specially when there is space for a whole range of algorithms: from the beginner use of trial division, to the more general version of [polynomial time primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test), passing through a cleaver and intuitive use of a [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Also, include the specific issues you are facing.

This help us identify the problem without trying to get into your mind and read a lot of line of, possibly very broken, code.

**2. Name your variable accordingly**

Do you really work better with `userInt1` rather than with, say, `upperLimit` or `dwUpperLimit`, `ui32UpperLimit`?

**3. Known your data size**

Make the effort to recognize what data should take space in memory at runtime and what should not.
`upperLevel` and `lowerLevel` would be best declared with `EQU` (or any MASM equivalent).

If you support at most 400 numbers, why would you allocate 500 DWORDs for the array?
I am probably missing something but in the case I'm not, this may be symptom of a lazy or not-toward-programming attitude, get rid of it if you are interested in programming.

I'm not expecting you to know how to properly use the [pi(x) function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) and estimation techniques but you need at most 400 DWORDs (pro-tip: merge with point 2 `EQU` use).

**4. Divide the problem into sub-problems, with functions**

This really helps debugging and preventing mistakes in assembly.

**5. Indent your code and keep it clear**

Assembly code has no rule for indentation, but as human beings we automatically find a style that is a pleasure to read.

Remember to physically separate logically different piece of code, you do something with headlines comments but the whole cycling logic is messed up, if you keep programming in assembly you'll find out that you can write very clear code even with multiple jumps.

---

All this is just to make a **joke** and answer your *data question*:

```
goodBye     BYTE    "Impressed? Bye! ", 0
```

with a *data answer*

```
strGoodBye db "Not very much :)", 0
```